# В чем смысл char (*) [...]?

Tags: c++, c

Недавно нашел такой код:

```
struct dlist {
    struct dlist *next;
    struct dlist *prev;
};
#define DECLARE_DLIST(head_type, type, field)\
union head_type {\
    struct dlist list;\
    union {\
        char (*offset)[offsetof(type, field)];\
        type *t;\
    } *data;\
}
```

Не пойму, что значит `char (*offset)[offsetof(type, field)]`, точнее, как это работает.

Если у нас есть структура:

```
struct Some
{
    int int_data;
    struct dlist list_data;
};
```

и мы создаем новый `dlist`:

```
DECLARE_DLIST(head_type, struct Some, list_data) new_list;
```

Тогда в объединении будет `char (*offset)[4];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Таков синтаксис определения *указателя на массив*:

```
char (*offset)[offsetof(type, field)];
```

Здесь `offset` — это указатель на `char [offsetof(type, field)]`, т. е. `char (*)[offsetof(type, field)]`.

Если бы мы убрали круглые скобки вокруг `*`:

```
char *offset[offsetof(type, field)];
```

то член `offset` структуры имел бы тип *массива указателей*, т. е. `char * [offsetof(type, field)]`.

---

<sup>1. К слову, для расшифровки объявлений в языке C существует интересный инструмент — [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/).</sup>

<sup>2. Стоит подробнее почитать про т. н. *[правило чтения по спирали](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)*.</sup>

Comment: спасибо огромное! Получается с помощью sizeof(offset) мы можем узнать размер указателя на массив и этот размер и есть смещение.

Comment: @AkmubiLin, нет, смещением будет не размер указателя на массив, а размер самого массива, т. е. выражение `*offset`.

Comment: да, точно. sizeof(*offset).